# Django Admin Group Issue

Tags: django, django-admin, nginx, django-authentication, uwsgi

I hope you can help me.

The thing is, I was editing a user via Django Admin, and tried to add a new group from there. The add group page didn't showed up, and uWSGI log showed as follow:

```
*** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 3 (pid: 4763) ***
HARAKIRI: --- uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 4763) WAS managing request /admin/auth/group/add/ since Mon Apr 18 13:00:19 2011 ---
DAMN ! process 4763 died :( trying respawn ...
```

Then I found out that I can't access group Admin at all! Does anyone knows what is happening here?

Thanks!

#### ##### EDIT #####

It seems that the problem is the request takes to much time to process, and uWSGI kills it, while django test server doesn't, so in django test server the request is processed after a long while though.
I'm using Django_debug_toolbar, here is some info:

```
Resource    Value
User CPU time   4364.273 msec
System CPU time 964.061 msec
Total CPU time  5328.334 msec
Elapsed time    5541.512 msec
Context switches    10983 voluntary, 1053 involuntary
```

---

```
SQL
346 queries in 177.71ms
```

If anymore data would help finding a solution, just ask me, I couldn't think of anything more relevant to add here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is a problem with Django... Upgraded to version 1.3 and it got better. Didn't solved the problem though, it still takes a long time to query everything... But it's usable. Thanks everyone, I'm moving this thread to Django Bugs since it's their problem... Although, if anyone wants to post a patch to fix it would be really welcomed. I think someone already did this patch in Django community though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on here - it looks like the process has died for some unknown reason. Does restarting it help?

If not, try running the same code with the Django development runserver and DEBUG on to see if you can find the underlying error.

Comment: well, I'm actually at my development server with DEBUG on already. But even in django server it didn't showed nothing, the same error appears, page tryied to load but nothing.

Comment: Oh! That's something strange, actually, while I was commenting, the page loaded, after, almost a whole minute. It appears that uWSGI is killing the process after not receiving answer for a while, while django server doesn't do that, so the answer comes out. Any thoughts about what is making this request takes so long? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have some very inefficient code, and too many SQL queries. Check you're doing do the same calculations over and over in for loops and look into select_related() for the SQL queries.

Comment: Actually, it is a problem with Django... Upgraded to version 1.3 and it got better. Didn't solved the problem though, it still takes a long time to query everything... But it's usable. Thanks everyone, I'm moving this thread to Django Bugs since it's their problem... Although, if anyone wants to post a patch to fix it would be really welcomed. I think someone already did this patch in Django community though. Thanks